# change php curl script to ruby

Tags: php, ruby, curl

I need to change following php script into ruby script.

```
$url = '<ip>/api/ticket/create';
   $node_params = json_encode(array('type' => 'ticket',
          'value1' => $var1,
          'value2' => $var2,
          'value3' => $var3
        ));

        $curl_node = curl_init($url);
        $a1 = curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        $a2 = curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $a3 = curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $node_params);

        curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
        $node_response = curl_exec($curl_node);

        curl_close($curl_node);
```

Here i have done so far

```
  def create_ticket
    node_params={
       'type'       => 'ticket',
      'value1'      => @var1,
      'value2'      => @var2,
      'value3'      => @var3
    }.to_json
    apiurl      = "<ip>/api/ticket/create"
    easy        = Curl::Easy.new
    easy.header_in_body = true
    easy.url    = apiurl
    result      = easy.http_post(apiurl,node_params)
    puts result.inspect 
  end
```

but it's not working and i can't figure out the mistake. Help me guys.